# How to add Active class for a selected post in React.js

Tags: css, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm displaying list of posts on the page. Now when the user select a post I need to add a CSS active style to it but here it is applying to all the posts on the page. Though I'm applying the class conditionally but it's not resolving the issue. Can some one tell me where I'm doing wrong. For your reference find the link to codesandbox.

[`https://codesandbox.io/s/3x36m4kkom`](https://codesandbox.io/s/3x36m4kkom)

Comment: Your sandbox does not seem to be in a working state right now. It just says "Please select a Post" and nothing else.

Comment: I just checked it's working alright. please try it "Open in New Window"

Comment: I've updated your sandbox to add support for redux devtools which makes it much easier to track what is going on.

Comment: Oh yeah I got it now. I thought of comparing the selectedPost id and props id but I completely forgot about ownProps which comes as second argument as this is a optional argument in mapStateToProps. I was literally banging my head how props will come. Now I got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `PostItem.jsx` you have the following:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { onSelectPost } from "../actions/index";

const PostItem = props => (
  <div
    onClick={() => props.onSelectPost(props)}
    className={!props.active ? "card" : "card border border-primary"}
    style={{ width: "24rem" }}
  >
    <div className="card-body">
      <h5 className="card-title">{props.title}</h5>
      <p className="card-text">{props.body}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
);

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  active: state.active
});
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  onSelectPost: post => dispatch(onSelectPost(post))
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(PostItem);
```

You are using `state.active` in `mapStateToProps` to control the CSS class. There is nothing post-specific about this state property. It is a single boolean that will have an effect on every post.

If I change your `mapStateToProps` to the following:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
  active: state.selectedPost.id === ownProps.id
});
```

it seems to work.

[image: Edit r821j89oo]